# how to get firstname and lastname of Android phone owner?

Tags: android, contacts

Is there a way to get the firstname and lastname of Android phone owner? I've search the internet but I have no luck. I stumbled upon [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4301064/how-to-get-the-firstname-and-lastname-from-android-contacts) question in Stackoverlow but this is getting firstname and lastname of all contacts. What I need is just to get the owner's firstname and lastname.

Answer (score 23):

I think this is available ICS onwards only - Look at this for more info http://android-codelabs.appspot.com/resources/tutorials/contactsprovider/ex1.html

```
Cursor c = activity.getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);
int count = c.getCount();
String[] columnNames = c.getColumnNames();
boolean b = c.moveToFirst();
int position = c.getPosition();
if (count == 1 && position == 0) {
    for (int j = 0; j < columnNames.length; j++) {
        String columnName = columnNames[j];
        String columnValue = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(columnName)));
        ...
        //Use the values
    }
}
c.close();
```

Android includes a personal profile that represents the device owner - this profile is known as the "Me" profile and is stored in the `ContactsContract.Profile` table. You can read data from the user's profile so long as you

**add the READ_PROFILE and READ_CONTACTS permission in your AndroidManifest.xml.**

The most relevant fields for you are the DISPLAY_NAME column from the Contact and possibly the StructuredName fields

Comment: at least, how can i execute this code if it is ICS? ContactsContract.Profile.CONTENT_URI is giving me error.

Comment: You have to add android:targetSdkVersion="16" to your uses-sdk in the manifest since it is ICS and above

Comment: Did it work for you ? Or do you need more help setting it up ?

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
final AccountManager manager = AccountManager.get(this);
final Account[] accounts = manager.getAccountsByType("com.google");
final int size = accounts.length;
String[] names = new String[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
  names[i] = accounts[i].name;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I Had search on this thing and get some likes hope it will helpful to you.

- [How can I get the first name (or full name) of the user of the phone?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9323207/how-can-i-get-the-first-name-or-full-name-of-the-user-of-the-phone)
- [Android - Get UserData using AccountManager / First and Last name of the phone owner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367283/android-get-userdata-using-accountmanager-first-and-last-name-of-the-phone-o)